# Data attribute - return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to `jQuery` and having some trouble getting a data attribute to print in my HTML, can anyone help please?

I basically need to save the 'data-options' attribute on click and to copy it into a URL within the HTML.

I will have several links and want to update the pagename(.asp) in the URL depending on which link is clicked. So if I click on the first link, the URL will become url/pagename.asp, the second link will make it url/pagename2.asp

```js
$( ".myModal-copy" ).click(function() {
 var copyurl = $(this).data("options");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-copy" data-options="pagename" class="myModal-copy">Link</a>
http://www.url/<%=copyurl%>.asp
```

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up your asp and js - `copyurl` is a js variable but you are trying to output it using asp.,  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, looks like I am. I will have several links and want to update the pagename(.asp) in the URL depending on which link is clicked. 
So if I click on the first link, the URL will become http://www.url/pagename.asp, the second link will make it http://www.url/pagename2.asp

Comment: You need to show the html for where these urls are, at the moment it looks as if it is just a textnode on your page - if it is, then you will need to wrap it in a span and target that in your onclick.  If it is in a link, then you need to show us that in your question

Answer (score 0):

Get the the value of `data-options` then just `concatenate` `(+)` it to get required `URL`.

```js
$(".myModal-copy" ).click(function() {
 var copyurl = $(this).data("options");
console.log(copyurl);
console.log("http://www.url/<%="+copyurl+"%>.asp");
$("#url").text("http://www.url/<%="+copyurl+"%>.asp");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-copy" data-options="pagename" class="myModal-copy">Link</a>
   <p id="url">http://www.url/<%=copyurl%>.asp</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

first wrap your text in a html element
you can get the text of element using .text method then replace part of that string and write that updated text back to that element.

```js
$( ".myModal-copy" ).click(function() {
 var copyurl = $(this).data("options");
    var existingUrl = $('span').text();
    $('span').text(existingUrl.replace('<%=copyurl%>', copyurl)); // update text in the span by replacing the placeholder
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-copy" data-options="pagename" class="myModal-copy">Link</a>
<span>http://www.url/<%=copyurl%>.asp</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, appreciate your help.

Based on your answers the below code worked for me:

```js
$(".myModal-copy" ).click(function() {
 var copyurl = $(this).data("options");
  $("#url").text(copyurl);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-copy" data-options="pagename" class="myModal-copy">Link</a>
   <p id="url">http://www.url/.asp</p>
```